# Docker compose up command returns Could not start a new session. error

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I want to run 2 containers: one for chrome driver and one for selenium tests.
But I get this error.

```
| [ERROR] Tests run: 5, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3, Time elapsed: 17.253 s <<< FAILURE! - in tests.uitests.SurveyDesignerTest
survey_designer-selenium-tests-1   | [ERROR] tests.uitests.SurveyDesignerTest.setUpAndOpenSurveyDesignerPage[org.testng.TestRunner@35c12c7a](0)  Time elapsed: 16.534 s  <<< FAILURE!
survey_designer-selenium-tests-1   | org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
survey_designer-selenium-tests-1   | Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
survey_designer-selenium-tests-1   | Host info: host: '1e6e1f723981', ip: '172.28.0.3'
survey_designer-selenium-tests-1   | Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989'
survey_designer-selenium-tests-1   | System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '11.0.12'
survey_designer-selenium-tests-1   | Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  selenium-tests:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - selenium-chrome
    networks:
      - tgm-test-network

  selenium-chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
#    image: seleniarm/standalone-chromium
    shm_size: 2gb
#    privileged: true
    environment:
#      - SE_OPTS="--log-level FINE"
      - SE_ENABLE_TRACING=true
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps=
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    networks:
      - tgm-test-network

networks:
  tgm-test-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Can you please advice what can be problem here?